# Импорт класса из модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, импорт

Написал класс, импортирую его в другой Python файл. Однако после импорта в результате выдается `<class '__example__.ExampleClass'>`. Как его правильно обозначить, чтобы вывод был корректным.

Пример класса:

```
class Alpha(object):

    def __init__(self):
       self.cross()

    def cross(self):
       print('Hello World')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    attribute = Alpha()
```

Импорт:

```
 import __example__ as ex

 print(ex.Alpha)
```

Результат: 
      `<class '__example__.ExampleClass'>`

Comment: А что такое `__example__`? Можете написать название файла, где класс определён?

Comment: Файл `__example__.py`, если я правильно Вас понял

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под корректным выводом? Вы вывели класс, класс и вывелся.

Comment: Там определен класс. Я хочу его импортировать, но вывод вот какой.

Comment: `print(ex.Alpha)` - вывод класса (не переменной этого класса) `Alpha`. Чтоб создать переменную, нужно писать `Alpha()`. И у класса `Alpha` нет специального метода `__str__`, поэтому вывод как раз ожидаем

Comment: Импортировали Вы его в первой строке второго блока. Что именно из класса Вам нужно вывести?

Comment: Само содержимое класса, т.е Hello World.

Comment: Если не критиковать Ваше понимание "содержимого класса", ответ ниже.

Comment: Прошу простить мое невежество и неправильное поставление вопроса, я еще новичок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял в вопросе, автор хочет, чтобы сработал метод `__init__` класса. Для этого необходимо создать объект.

```py
import __example__ as ex

obj = ex.Alpha()
```

Однако хотелось бы заметить, что строка, выводимая при создании объекта (т.е. при срабатывании метода `__init__`), отнюдь не является содержимым класса (если закрыть глаза на сомнительность самого термина). Чтобы наделить класс, а точнее его объект, каким-либо "содержимым", стоит, по крайней мере, определить его свойство. Я бы сделал это как-то так:

```py
class Alpha(object):

    content = 'Hello world'

    def get_content(self):
        return content
```

Тогда второй файл выглядел бы так:

```py
import __example__ as ex

obj = ex.Alpha()

print(obj.get_content())
```